# What is the difference between python float value and c float value?

Tags: python, c

I was going through the same question in two different languages. Got different results. Need help to understand why this is happening?

I wrote the same code in python and got a different result than what was expected from C.

Code 1:

```c
{
  float f = 0.1;
  if (f == 0.1)
    printf("YES\n");
  else
    printf("NO\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```py
f = float()
f = 0.1
if (f == 0.1):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Both must give the same output as NO. But only C is giving the expected output while Python is giving the output as YES.

Comment: This is why you never compare floats using `==`.

Comment: In your python code, the first line `f = float()` doesn't make `f` be a float in your code. You can remove it and you will get the same result. A case when you would want to use the `float` function is when you have an integer or a string that you want to convert to a float, as in `f=float(1)` or `f=float("0.1")`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your C-Code you compare float `0.1` with double 0.1, where the float value is first converted to double, where, due to limited precision this gives `0.10000000149011612` which is not the same value as the double `0.1`.

In Python `float` is the internally the same as `double` in C. And double 0.1 is the same as double 0.1.

So Python gives the expected output `YES` and C gives to not so obvious output `NO`.